# Angular 11 and .Net post method not working

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-core, http-post

I am trying to post data from Angular side to .Net and I'm not hits the breakpoint at Controller c#.
Do I need some configuration? I have already sent data in this way in Angular 8 before and  it was working.

**c#**

```
   public class UpdateViewModel
      {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
      }


    [HttpPost]
    [Route("delete")]
    public void delete(UpdateViewModel model)
    {
        //return Ok();
    }
```

**ts**

```
  var model = {
  Id: 1,
  Title: 'test'
}



  return this.http.post(this.baseURL + "home/delete/", model)
  .pipe(
    retry(1),
    catchError(this.errorHandler)
  );
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the right code? You show a post method with the route "delete", but you show a get call to "home/SearchConnections/". That doesn't match up at all.

Comment: calling Post method with "http.get"? and URL looks wrong as well

Comment: Im so sorry wrong code. Now its correct

Comment: Can you please be more specific about what error are you getting? Is it a 404? In that case it could be your controller missing a [Route] attribute. Is it a 400? May be your server is configured to expect camelCase json or something. Is the request not being sent at all?  May be you are not subscribing to the observable at all. There could be many other reasons why this is not working.

Comment: Yeah I was sure I have subscribe in component :/ I  didn't get any error :/ Just nothing happend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the http client of angular is based on observables. This means, the request will only be sent if you subscribe to the observable. You can do this with `.subscribe()`or with `.toPromise()`.

For your code:

```
  return this.http.post(this.baseURL + "home/delete/", model)
    .pipe(
      retry(1),
    )
    .subscribe({
      error: this.errorHandler
    });
```

Comment: Thank you! I was sure I have subscribe in component where I call this method from service :/